# onMouseEnter/onMouseOver not working on new NextJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have created a new NextJS project with the latest version of Next (Next.js v13.4.19). I want to register onMouseEnter events for my application. A basic example works in this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-saha-9mvvwy?file=/index.js.

I use a simple `sudo yarn create next-app --typescript` and then paste the Box code on the home page. My page.tsx looks like so:

```
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box
      color="primary"
      onMouseOver={(e) => console.log("onMouseEnter (first button)")}
      onMouseOut={(e) => console.log("onMouseLeave (first button)")}
    >
      Hello World Edit
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I get an error about needing to specify if this is a client or server component, so I add the "use client" modifier at the top:

```
'use client'

import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box
      color="primary"
      onMouseOver={(e) => console.log("onMouseEnter (first button)")}
      onMouseOut={(e) => console.log("onMouseLeave (first button)")}
    >
      Hello World Edit
    </Box>
  );
}
```

There are no errors, but the events are not getting registered. Any suggestions?

Comment: At least in the CodeSandbox, it seems to work for me. The events do get logged into the console when I hover above the text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by downgrading my version of next from 13.4 to 13.0.6 in package.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `createRoot` to render your app.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  return (
    <Box
      color="primary"
      onMouseEnter={(e) => console.log("onMouseEnter (first button)")}
      onMouseLeave={(e) => console.log("onMouseLeave (first button)")}
    >
      Hello World
    </Box>
  );
}

const app = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))

app.render(<App />);
```

Code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sky-2cskff